# Add class to first child using javascript

Tags: javascript

is there any reason this chain does not work? It does not add the class:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0].firstChild.className = "current"
```

It should return the first child of the nav element which is an `<a>` which does not happen.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the syntax at least correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you have [**text nodes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType) between `nav` and `a`. You can filter them by [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType):

```
var childNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0].childNodes;
for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (childNodes[i].nodeType !== 3) { // nodeType 3 is a text node
      childNodes[i].className = "current";  // <a>
      break;
    }        
}
```

It may seem strange but, for example, if you have the following markup:

```
<nav>
<a>afsa</a>
</nav>
```

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ccbEP/)**.

Why does this happen? Because *some* browsers may interpret the space between `<nav>` and `<a>` as an *extra* text node. Thus, `firstChild` will no longer work since it'll return the text node instead.

If you had the following markup, it'd **[work](http://jsfiddle.net/nMbP4/)**:

```
<nav><a>afsa</a></nav>
```

Comment: could you explain what it childNodes[i].nodeType !== 3 means?

Comment: @SnippetSpace: Sure, I've edited my answer. It ignores text nodes, since for them, `nodeType` has the value `3`.

Comment: got it to work. thanks for the explanation :). Small error in your code to make it do what I want. childNodes[i].className = "current"; should be childNodes[1].className = "current"; to make the "first child" thing work :)

Comment: @SnippetSpace: Or use a `for`-loop as I did. This way, it doesn't matter how many text nodes you have, you'll always ignore them. You're welcome, glad I could help.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].className = "current"` would do it without a loop (assuming there will always be at least one `nav` containing at least one `a`)...

Answer (score 5):

You can simply document.querySelectorAll to select the list.
use "firstElementChild" to get first child node and add class.

```
 const firstChild = document.querySelectorAll('nav').firstElementChild;
 firstChild.classList.add('current');
```

Answer (score 2):

The statement:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0].firstChild.className = "current"
```

is somewhat fragile as any change in the assumed document structure breaks your code. So more robust do do something like:

```
var links, 
    navs = document.getElementsByTagName('nav');

if (navs) links = nav[0].getElementsByTagName('a');

if (links) links[0].className = links[0].className + ' ' + 'current';
```

You should also have robust addClassName and removeClassName functions.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery can make this very easy:

```
$("#nav:first-child").addClass("current");
```

Comment: I want to learn Javascript. Already know jQuery and find it more satisfying to write pure code.

Comment: true, but he didn't specifically say not jquery either, and a lot of things are much simpler in jquery

Comment: Even assuming jQuery is OK your selector is still wrong: you're selecting an element with the _id_ `nav` if it is the first child of its parent. OP wants to select the first child of a `<nav>` element. (Something more like this: `"nav > a:first-child"`.)