# Assigning z-index to Javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, html, css, plugins, z-index

I am trying to embed the LinkedIn plugin onto a website. However, since the layout of this website includes stacked images (using `z-index`), I am trying to assign the plugin to a CSS class to assign it a `z-index` and position it in the correct location.

This has not worked for me so far, any suggestions for other implementations? Below are snippets of my code.

HTML codes:

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript" 
class = "linkedin"></script>

<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data- 
id="MY_LINK" data- 
format="hover" data-related="false" class = "linkedin"></script>
```

CSS codes:

```
.linkedin
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 60%;
    left: 40%;
}
```

Comment: you cannot style a script tag

Comment: You would need to identify specific classname from injected HTML by the script and assign z-index to it.

Comment: You need to first of all understand that these script elements are not the actual content that gets displayed - their job only is to _get_ that content and place it in the document. Start by inspecting the actual content you want to format in your browser’s dev tools, and then figure out to which elements z-index should be applied to, to get the desired result, and what characteristics they have that would make them selectable (Ids, classes, position in relation to other elements.)

Answer (score 2):

The script tag is just an import of the LinkedIn javascript file into your application. It doesn't render at all.

The LinkedIn javascript file generates additional HTML in your page at runtime. This HTML should be customized.

Hopefully there are unique classes and IDs on the generated HTML that allows you to apply specific styles to every HTML element. You can use <kbd>F12</kbd> in your browser to examine the pattern of the generated HTML and add CSS accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If the script does not generate class names or ids you can use a javascript function to get child elements of child elements and so on until you are able to get the node that you want and assign a class to it. I had to do this recently with some script generated code. Obviously this is just an example. In my situation I needed to get several elements generated by the script so I had to use for statements and lists. If you are only trying to access one element you probably won't need to do that. So forgive the complexity of this example but you can see that by getting child nodes and being sure to eliminate any undefineds, nulls and childless elements that were generated by the script I was eventually able to get the list of nodes I wanted so I could iterate through them and change their styling as needed. So even if your elements don't have a class or id specified you should be able to find a way to get them and then use js to set their class to a class you defined in your CSS.

This overflow question covers that last part in more detail and has a good example of getting just a single element using the method described - [Add class to first child using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361616/add-class-to-first-child-using-javascript)

**[EDIT]**
Also with z-index you will want to make sure you intentionally remove any styling that designates float. It may not be enough to just add absolute positioning. If you can remove all styling and then apply your own styling that would be best. Float elements can't be z postitioned and often times script generated code is float positioned. 
**[EDIT]**

```
var listRows = document.getElementById("extHGrid").childNodes;
    //debugging
    //console.log(listRows);

    //iterate through listRows, removing undefined or childless objects while adding the rest to listUsers (this returns all the user divs in the content block)
    var listUsers = [];
    listUsers = [];
    for (r = 0; r < listRows.length; r++) {
        if (listRows[r] !== undefined && listRows[r].children !== null && listRows[r].children[0] !== undefined) {
            listUsers.push(listRows[r].children[0]);
        }
    }
    //debugging
    console.log(listUsers);

    /* 
     *iterate through divs in content block, get child containing return time and add it to listTimers
     * assumes return time is in last column/child element/ span of div
     */
    var listTimers = [];
    listTimers = [];
    for (t = 0; t < listUsers.length; t++) {
        if (listUsers[t] !== undefined && listUsers[t].children !== null) {
            listTimers.push(listUsers[t].lastElementChild);
        }
    }
    //dubugging
    console.log(listTimers);

    //iterate through divs in content block, get child containing identifier and add it to listTimers
    var listUserIdentity = [];
    listUserIdentity = [];
    for (u = 0; u < listUsers.length; u++) {
        if (listUsers[u] !== undefined && listUsers[u].children !== null) {
            /*
             * change children[1] to children[pos] where pos == position of child containing identifer in children index of div 
             * if identifier is in different position - identifier can be name, UserSys or anything so long as it is unique to each user and not null or " "
             */
            listUserIdentity.push(listUsers[u].children[1]);
        }
    }
    //dubugging
    console.log(listUserIdentity);
```